# Access a foreign project's PubSub with com.google.cloud.pubsub API

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I have an AppEngine app that publishes messages to PubSub.
Now I want to read those messages from a different GCP project.
This is possible using **com.google.apis/google-api-services-pubsub** v1-rev8-1.21.0 and a service-account key.

I took the examples from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java as a guide.
Parts of the code are a bit ugly (e. g. requiring a RetryHttpInitializerWrapper) so I was wondering if it's possible to achieve the same using
**com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub** v. 0.4.0

However I couldn't figure out how to specify a different project.
All examples simply use

```
PubSub pubsub = PubSubOptions.defaultInstance().service();
```

which gives me my own project's instances.
How can I tell PubSub to use a different projectId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In v0.4.0 of the google-cloud-java library, you can use the [PubSubOptions.Builder](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.4.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/pubsub/PubSubOptions.Builder.html) to create your PubSubOptions. You would use the [projectId](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.4.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.Builder.html#projectId(java.lang.String)) method to set the project. Note that in v0.5.0, this method was deprecated in favor of [setProjectId](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.5.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/ServiceOptions.Builder.html#setProjectId(java.lang.String)).